# why does this imapclient g++ compiling gets errors

Tags: c++, g++, imap

Im a beginner level Java coder and I decided to get into C++ coding. After reading the basics (similar enought to Java) decided to try the apoach of reading other peoples code.
I found the following code of an imap mail client, but when triing to compile it with g++ (gcc 4.6.3) it shows some errors that seem to have something to do with the scope of the used namespaces.
Where is the error here or what kind of error should i be 'googling' for?, 'cause I couldn find the answer there.

Here's a link to the code, 'cause Im not sure about licensing issues (like if I should be citing the author):

[imap_email_client](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/531592/Simple-IMAP-CLIENT)

Thanks in advance for all your help and sorry for all the forum rules missconceptions i could have commited.

Comment: Maybe it's because g++ doesn't compile C#!

Comment: Don't be scared of the forum. :) But yes, the code you linked to is not C++.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum but a Question and Answer site.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Sam Miller I was using the word forum in a general sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The code you referenced isn't any **C++** code, but code written in a language called **C#**.

On the other hand `g++` is just a C++ compiler. Meaning it doesn't know any C# and it will not compile any C# code.

You'll need a C# compiler instead to compile the code you referenced. As Mono (see: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) comes along with a C# compiler `gmcs` you might want to try if you're able to compile with

```
gmcs name-of-your-source-file
```

if it is installed on your system.

On my system I was able to compile the referenced sources with it.